# Spring Boot thymeleaf can not find css file

Tags: spring-boot, thymeleaf

I have a spring boot program that uses thymeleaf.   The web page loads.  But the web page cannot find my css files.  I see the follow logged by spring boot.  The web page is loaded with this url: http://localhost:9090/lotto/rawdataocc.

- No mapping for GET /lotto/lotto.css

The CSS file is under resources/static directory

The thymleleaf template is under templates directory.

```
<!DOCTYPE html SYSTEM "http://www.thymeleaf.org/dtd/xhtml1-strict-thymeleaf-4.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Historical Lotto Number Occurances</title>


    <link th:href="@{lotto.css}" rel="stylesheet" />


    <!--
    <style>
        #customers {
          font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
          border-collapse: collapse;
          width: 100%;
        }

        #customers td, #customers th {
          border: 1px solid #ddd;
          padding: 8px;
        }

        #customers tr:nth-child(even){background-color: #f2f2f2;}

        #customers tr:hover {background-color: #ddd;}

        #customers th {
          padding-top: 12px;
          padding-bottom: 12px;
          text-align: left;
          background-color: #4CAF50;
          color: white;
        }
    </style>
    -->
</head>
    <body>
        <table id="customers" >
            <tr>
                <th>Lotto Number</th>
                <th>Occurrence</th>
            </tr>
            <tr th:each="list: ${list}">
                <td th:text="${list.lottoNumber}" />
                <td th:text="${list.occurance}" />
            </tr>
        </table>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

What you're missing is a single slash `/`.

Instead of:

```
<link th:href="@{lotto.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

... do:

```
<link th:href="@{/lotto.css}" rel="stylesheet" />
```

This will make your url context-relative instead of page-relative ([link](https://www.thymeleaf.org/doc/tutorials/3.0/usingthymeleaf.html#link-urls))